# selecting items that come after a specific value

Tags: mysql

Say this is my sql:

```
  SELECT title,
         author,
         ISBN 
    FROM bs_books 
ORDER BY ISBN 
   LIMIT 3
```

It just selects everything from a certain table (title, author, etc..).

Say I would like to select all the items that come after a certain title, not alphabetically or something but just the records after the certain element. How would I approach this?

Comment: You need *something* to order the result by. Otherwise, you won't get a constant order. Which column do you want to order it by?

Comment: what's wrong with select * from bs_books where isbn <= '....' order by isbn. What am I missing?

Comment: well what i'm looking for is all items that come after a certain title. like the following:say i have a book with title "rings" the it should show: "SELECT * FROM bs_books starting from book where title = "rings" ORDER BY ISBN. Freaky syntax but maybe its a bit better explained this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the ISBN for the title you want following-ISBNs for, then simply:

```
SELECT title, author, ISBN
FROM bs_books
WHERE ISBN>'978-3-16-148410-0' -- or whatever ISBN
ORDER BY ISBN
LIMIT 3
```

If you want to select it from just the title in one go, you could use a self-join:

```
SELECT b1.title, b1.author, b1.ISBN
FROM bs_books AS b0
JOIN bs_books AS b1 ON b1.ISBN>b0.ISDN
WHERE b0.title='Title for which to get following ISBNs'
ORDER BY b1.ISBN
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OFFSET somenumber` to start at a given numeric position. Maybe that's also ok for you?

If there is a primary key with auto-increment, you can do something like `WHERE pk>=somenumber`.

Comment: I am not using any increment, and ordering by a number doesnt work aswell, can order by ISBN number thou